# GNU Radio build error

Tags: boost, build, gnuradio

I am trying to build GNU Radio. But I am getting the following error when I am trying to run make.

I followed the steps mentioned in README.building-boost

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$BOOST_PREFIX/lib

$ cd <path-to-top-of-gnuradio-tree>
$ ./bootstrap
$ ./configure --with-boost=$BOOST_PREFIX  # plus whatever config args you usually use
```

But when I run make, I get this error :

```
/usr/local/lib/libgruel-3.4.1git.so.0: undefined reference to `boost::thread::start_thread()'
```

I wrote a simple program using Boost Thread and was able to compile and run it.

Any idea how to fix the build issue?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but if you use Ubuntu, then use this script:
www.sbrac.org/files/build-gnuradio

it works really good, you may have to run it 2 times to get everything working, but it saves a lot of time fixing the problems of dependency like the one you were dealing with.

Comment: Usually, you shouldn't need to run it twice nowadays!